# Test suite for population-count function, using random input

Tags: python, unit-testing

For the purpose of this discussion, I have the following function:

```
def countSetBits(num):
  cnt = 0
  while num:
    cnt += num & 0b1
    num >>= 1
  return cnt
```

It counts the number of set bits in a given `num`'s binary representation. For example, take `10` whose binary rep is `0b1010` -- `countSetBits(10)` should equal `2`.

I have written a "test suite" that generates random input -- numbers of known set bit count and use that to test my `countSetBits` function.

```
import random
import unittest

class TestCountSetBits(unittest.TestCase):
    NUM_TESTS = 100
    MAX_SET_BIT_CNT = 10
    def test_suite(self):
        for _ in range(self.NUM_TESTS):
            k = expectedCnt = random.randint(0, self.MAX_SET_BIT_CNT)

            # Generate a random integer with `k` set bits
            setBitPositions = random.sample(range(k * 2), k)
            num = sum(0b1 << pos for pos in setBitPositions)
            computedCnt = countSetBits(num)
            self.assertEqual(computedCnt,
                             expectedCnt,
                             msg=f'Got {computedCnt}, but expected {expectedCnt}')
        print('Success!')

TestCountSetBits().test_suite()
```

My questions are:

0. Should I use `cls` instead of `self`?
1. Is there a more pythonic way to write this "test suite". I may be reading too much into this, but Python Doc's unittest page has a Basic Example in which each `def test_*` has only one `assertEqual`. My `def test_suite` has the `assertEqual` inside a `for` loop. Is this bad style?
2. Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks!

Scrolling down the unittest page, I see `subTest` which may tidy things up:

```
class TestCountSetBits(unittest.TestCase):
    NUM_TESTS = 100
    MAX_SET_BIT_CNT = 10
    def test_suite(self):
        for _ in range(self.NUM_TESTS):
            k = expectedCnt = random.randint(0, self.MAX_SET_BIT_CNT)

            # Generate a random integer with `k` set bits
            setBitPositions = random.sample(range(k * 2), k)
            num = sum(0b1 << pos for pos in setBitPositions)
            computedCnt = countSetBits(num)

            # Diff starts here
            with self.subTest():
                self.assertEqual(computedCnt,
                                 expectedCnt,
                                 msg=f'Got {computedCnt}, but expected {expectedCnt}')
            # Diff ends here

        print('Success!')

TestCountSetBits().test_suite()
```

Comment: I don't know why it isn't mentioned, Python `int` class has a built-in member function called `bit_count` and it does exactly what `countSetBits` does, except it is implemented in C and thus way more efficient. And it should be used in production code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## PEP-8

```
def countSetBits(num):
```

Ummm, yeah, let me stop you right there.
Pythonically we would avoid the java-esque camelCase.
And maybe even let the Gentle Reader know we anticipate an `int`
that we can do bit operations on.
And describe what we return.

```
def count_set_bits(num: int) -> int:
```

In many languages we would conventionally name that
[pop_count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight).
Ξένη Γήινος observes that this is
re-inventing the wheel since the builtin
[bit_count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_count)
gives the identical answer much quicker.

Similar snake_case remarks for {expected,computed}_cnt
and for set_bit_positions.
The `unittest` module is rather old,
and comes from a time when we had fewer clear conventions,
hence names like `assertEqual`.

For extra pythonic brownie points,
write a single English sentence as a """docstring""".

---

```
    def test_suite(self):
        ...
        for _ in range(self.NUM_TESTS):
            ... self.MAX_SET_BIT_CNT ...
```

> 0. Should I use `cls` instead of `self`?

No.

There are times for such a practice, in your target code.
But not in this test code.

BTW, it's fine to invest zero effort in devising a name
for each test method.
The obvious name for this method would be `test_count_set_bits`.
The module being tested is presumably in `count_set_bits.py`,
and the `TestCountSetBits` class name you chose is absolutely perfect.
Typically there's not a ton of creativity that goes into making up
identifiers in a test, and we count that as a good thing,
we like simple boring tests.

> 1. ... has the assertEqual inside a for loop. Is this bad style?

No, not at all, it is just fine as-is.

A unit test should look like AAA, arrange act assert.
It *could* have just a single instance of that,
and then we move on to another AAA in the next test method.
But here, we have to do a bit of Arrange work before
we're ready for the rest, and it makes perfect sense
to loop as you have done.

An even simpler test method might start with

```
        self.assertEqual(count_set_bits(10), 2)
        self.assertEqual(count_set_bits(11), 3)
```

and that would be perfectly fine, no need for two methods.

We anticipate that most tests are Green, most of the time.
What's the downside to having multiple asserts in a test?
Some of them won't run in the event of Red failure.
So we learn less from that run.
It's a tradeoff.

If there is little Arrange overhead, create distinct tests.
If during arranging you had to go through a bunch of ceremony,
feel free to amortize that over multiple asserts in a single test method.

This is language-agnostic advice. There's nothing python specific about it.

EDIT

Let me revisit the two lines I proposed.
The first line came straight from your English language example
where you expressed ten as `10` in decimal notation,
and then I slightly tweaked the second line.
I'd like to respond to your comment about
"a lot of Arrange code" relative to small
amount of target code.

I feel a better way for me to express those two lines would be:

```
        self.assertEqual(count_set_bits(0b1010), 2)
        self.assertEqual(count_set_bits(0b1011), 3)
```

Now the Gentle Reader can visually scan the
input that we have Arranged and immediately see the answer.
That is to say, this test is now "obvious".

I count half a dozen characters of Arrange,
much less than the several lines which your
very nice and far more powerful test wound up using.
Both my boring test and your flexible test are good;
both belong in the test suite, as they do different things.
The small test has didactic value
while your longer test tries to exercise a larger portion
of the (infinite!) space of valid input values.
Also, significantly, the short test instills confidence
that the more flexible test is actually working properly.
Imagine that buggy target code always returned `0`,
and buggy test code accidentally cleared all bits so it
was asking for pop count of zero and wrongly showing us Green.
The dirt simple test would catch such a travesty.

> 2. Any suggestions are welcome!

I see what you're trying to do with the `0b1` thing that you left-shift,
and I'm somewhat sympathetic.
But it's kind of weird.
It's not like you're going for parallel structure with other nearby binary constants.
A `1` is going to mean the same thing in hex, decimal, octal, binary.
Recommend you just use `1` in the source.

Now, if we had e.g. `x & 255` masking and `x | 256` bit setting,
I would *definitely* insist on expressing those as `0xff` and `0x100`,
in order to prevent bugs via better readability.
But `1`? Meh.

I feel that verifying `count_set_bits(0) == 0`
is an important enough edge case that it's worth
coding manually, rather than hoping the PRNG
managed to hit it.

And then maybe walk a single bit up from `1` to
some power of two, verifying the count is always one.

> Scrolling down the unittest page, I see subTest

Hmmm, interesting.
I don't recall that I've ever seen
[subTest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.subTest)
used in production code that I've reviewed.
Thank you for bringing it to my attention.
Sure, go for it, use it in good health.

Imagine there was some population count bug.
Maybe it fails just for multiples of twelve.
Or maybe it always returns `0`.
In the first case, seeing that one-twelfth of tests
failed would be very informative, and might reduce debugging time.
In the second case, we'd be spammed with a ton of failures.
Use what you feel would best support your development efforts.
I'd be fine with either, since in both cases I will
work toward turning the tests completely Green,
and will definitely augment the automated test observations
with single-step observations from within a debugger.

---

## CLI

```
TestCountSetBits().test_suite()
```

I understand why you wrote this,
it is a perfectly sensible way to execute the test runner.
Especially when protected by a guard:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestCountSetBits().test_suite()
```

But I stopped appending such boilerplate to my tests long ago,
preferring to habitually run

```
$ python -m unittest tests/*_test.py
```

Or I let `$ make test` do that for me.
Or I ask [pytest](https://pypi.org/project/pytest)
to run it, while still inheriting from `TestCase`.
Typically that's because I want to make a `$ pytest --cov` code coverage
[measurement](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-cov).

---

## repeatable tests

I admire that you want to test "lots of inputs",
more adventurous inputs than the boring ones
you might have dreamt up and manually typed in.
But please understand that Random Tests Are Bad.
That is, if you get a failed Red test you won't
necessarily be able to learn much from it.
It's not a sure thing you can reproduce the bug.

So if you *do* go with random, definitely
[seed()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed)
the PRNG, maybe with `0`, or with `42`,
so that subsequent runs will test the same inputs.

Or use a PRNG *once* to produce `input.csv`,
and feed *that* same file to all subsequent test runs.

---

## torture test

Consider using the amazing
[hypothesis](https://pypi.org/project/hypothesis)
testing library, if you're keen to find the edge cases.

It's not always a fit.
It works best when you can offer an "oracle" for correctness,
such as reversible {serialize, deserialize}, {encrypt, decrypt},
or {compress, decompress} pairs.
It's very good at exploring the space of unusual inputs,
and then having found a failing input it will boil it
down to the simplest such failing input that it can find.

---

This codebase achieves its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and thoughtful answer.

In this example and putting aside the already mentioned pitfalls of random tests, the test code has arguably more logic than the code being tested. Is this a code smell? A hypothesis: if a test has too much logic, it'd probably be in the Arrange part of AAA, which is the case here.

Comment: I respectfully disagree, and I shared some remarks under > 1. EDIT. However, there is one code smell that might be surfaced in that way. It relates to the thoughtful design of your Public API. If caller has to jump through lots of hoops before being able to call your API, then maybe your API is "too hard" and should be simplified, re-thought, re-factored. For example `C(B(A(), p2), p3).reticulate_splines()` needs a ton of setup before we're in a position to reticulate those splines -- maybe class C doesn't really need all of that all the time, or maybe we need to split off a new class D.